# Error Handling in Pandas : TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

Tags: python, pandas

I need help figuring out what is causing the above-referenced error type in my code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Group the data by visibility levels and calculate the total number of rides for each group
merged_data = merged_data.groupby(pd.cut(merged_data['mean_visibility_miles'], bins=np.arange(0, 16, 2))).sum()

# Create a new variable "total_rides" which is the sum of "Subscriber" and "Customer"
merged_data["total_rides"] = merged_data["Subscriber"] + merged_data["Customer"]

# Plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(np.log(merged_data["total_rides"] + 1), marker="o")

# Convert the index to a list and replace commas with hyphens
labels = [str(label).replace(", ", " - ")[1:-1] for label in merged_data.index.tolist()]

# Set the new tick labels
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xlabel("Visibility (miles)")
ax.set_ylabel("Log(total rides + 1)")
ax.set_title("Total number of rides for different visibility levels")
plt.show()
```

Below is the error popping up:
[image]

Comment: merged data is consolidated data from four different csv files. The entire stack trace is very lenthy and I do not know to share that here

Comment: you can make minimal and reproducible test example like your dataset https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What are the `dtypes` of `merged_data`?

Comment: @grepgrok..it is float when I checked

Comment: @khali-blinks if merged_data is a DataFrame, when you call `merged_data.dtypes` it should return a Series with the column names and their datatypes. If merged_data is a Series, there will only be 1 data type (if there are multiple different ones, the dtype is object). Regardless of the type, in order to effectively diagnose your problem, I need more information on the structure of merged_data

Comment: yeah, you are right , I think my dataframe has a lot of nan which is causing this issue. I will check the datasets I merged together. There might be sth wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know more without knowing more about what `merged_data` is, its structure, and what you are trying to do. The error definitely seems to be coming from the fact that either your `Subscriber` or `Customer` columns is an interval.

If your goal is to plot the top and bottom of the interval, you may find it easiest to do it in two steps:

```py
merged_data["total_rides"] += 1
ax.plot(np.log([d.left for d in merged_data["total_rides"]]), marker="o")
ax.plot(np.log([d.right for d in merged_data["total_rides"]]), marker="o")
```

then we can even add a line between the two:

```py
# Precomputing values
x = merged_data["total_rides"]
left = [d.left for d in x]
right = [d.right for d in x]
x += 1
left = np.log(left)
right = np.log(right)

# Plotting top and bottom
for i in range(0, len(left)):
    y = [left[i], right[i]]
    ax.plot([i, i], y, 'o-')
```

Alternatively, you might be plotting it as a pair:

```py
ax.plot(left, right, marker="o")
```

Comment: @grepgrok...i get this error from the code you sent : AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'left'

Comment: @khali-blinks ah, I was trying to distribute the `.left` and `.right` through the Series. Fixed it now